# QBGLVideoView rotated when called getCurrentSession().switchCapturePosition(null)

Tags: android, webrtc, android-videoview, quickblox

I am working on [Quickblox videochat](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android). Everything works good, but the time I want to switch the camera i.e from front cam to the back cam by calling:

```
if (getCurrentSession() != null)
    getCurrentSession().switchCapturePosition(null);
```

It successfully switch the camera, but on the other side, i.e. on remote videoview of opponent, the view comes 180 degree rotated. 
And moreover the local videoview is also rotated. I tried using:

```
local_ongoing_call.setVideoViewOrientation(-90);
```

but, it rotates the view at my end, whereas the opponent is still having the same rotated view. Need help!

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate QBGLVideoView on opponent’s side. Seems like this issue is related to particular devices and webrtc library version. 
There should be new video calls released in the nearest future, so most probably the problem will be solved with the new version.

Comment: How can I rotate QBGLVideoView on opponent’s side?